# NodeJS MySQL and Promises - Cannot read property 'query' of undefined?

Tags: mysql, node.js, promise, node-mysql, nodejs-server

I'm just learning to use promises and unsure of this error that I'm getting;

```
  Cannot read property 'query' of undefined
```

I've simplified my query but still get the error. So I'm guessing it may have to do with the class I'm using for the MySQL database. Here's where I make the query;

```
var createAudiopost = async function(req, res, next){     
let row_a, row_b, row_c, row_d, row_e, row_f;    
try {    
    row_a = await mydb.query( 'SELECT * FROM audioposts'); 
     
     console.log("success");  
     res.json({     "title" : title, 
                    "userid" : userid,
                    "opid" : opid, 
                    "insert
            });     
}                           
catch(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
}
finally {
    mydb.close();
        }
}

 module.exports = createAudiopost;
```

And here's where I've created a class for the MySQL database;

```
const mysql = require( 'mysql' );

let config = {
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : 'user',
    password : 'password',
    database: 'database'
};

class DataBase {
    constructor( config ) {
        this.connection = mysql.createConnection( config );
    }
    query( sql, args ) {
        return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
            this.database.query( sql, args, ( err, rows ) => {
                if ( err )
                    return reject( err );
                resolve( rows );
            } );
        } );
    }
    close() {
        return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
            this.connection.end( err => {
                if ( err )
                    return reject( err );
                resolve();
            } );
        } );
    }
}

const mydb = new DataBase(config);
```

Why does my console tell me that the query is undefined?

Answer (score 0):

you need to bind your promise function:

```js
    query( sql, args ) {
        return new Promise( function ( resolve, reject ) {
            this.connection.query( sql, args, ( err, rows ) => {
                if ( err )
                    return reject( err );
                resolve( rows );
            } );
        }.bind(this) );
    }
```

Or you can use alias

```js
    query( sql, args ) {
        let that = this;
        return new Promise( function ( resolve, reject ) {
            that.connection.query( sql, args, ( err, rows ) => {
                if ( err )
                    return reject( err );
                resolve( rows );
            } );
        });
    }
```

Comment: I got : SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: For the 2nd example I just got the same error - 
Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

Comment: my fault, binding is not accepted with arrow functions, also, in your  code you have this.connection, not this.database

Comment: Would it be possible to revise your answer to reflect the necessary changes?